# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'cataloginventory_stock' for key 'UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE', que

Tags: html, mysql, css, magento-1.9

we are getting the below error in magento  store .please help us to sort out the issue

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'cataloginventory_stock' for key 'UNQ_INDEX_PROCESS_INDEXER_CODE', query was: INSERT INTO `index_process` (`indexer_code`,`status`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?)

appreciate for your efforts

Comment: we having one load balancer, request comes to loadbanacer   behind 2 apache and  master  master replication workes

Answer (score 0):

The message means you are inserting a value twice in your `indexer_code` field which seems to be defined as a UNIQUE field.

If you are inserting records, please make sure you won't insert twice the same record in a UNIQUE field.

Comment: hi theo  this error was occur  sometime in in magento store.can u  suggest to fix this error